# What happens to log history of comments done on a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Today I was reviewing a low quality answer from review queue. It seems the poster deleted the post afterwards as it already had 3 downvotes. Now that post is not visible to me when I go to [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324727/how-do-i-mock-the-method-getvalues-in-system-data-idatareader) as it got deleted.

The comment which I had made on the post is missing from my history log also when I check it in my profile dashboard? Why the comments are not visible in my profile dashboard?

Comment: [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNTy.png) of the deleted post.

Comment: It was not deleted by the OP but by 3 reviewers who handled the review task. By the way, that particular OP is known for his answers ...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments or if you want a feature request... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments

Comment: By the way, when you notice that a post is very low quality and also very old, it's usually not too productive to write out a comment for the answerer, because the post is most likely long abandoned. I'm not saying it's wrong to leave a comment, it's just likely to be a waste of your time. Recommend Deletion is more effective. (And with a user as experienced as Jon Skeet, you're preaching to the choir)

Comment: @4castle - Definition of old is bit subjective and can vary in the context of the post. To give a decision to delete a post requires you to dig much deeper and then your decision has to be endorsed by other reviewers as well. I would say it is a hard call in such a context and will vary in context of the post being reviewed. I have very high regards for Jon Skeet as a programmer and for a moment I thought I should rather skip that review but community responsibility/service is above everything.

Comment: The system in the past defines "old enough" as [60 days](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/), but I think it's safe to say that a post which is over 8 years old is well within "very old."

Comment: Great. I'll certainly consider this feedback in my reviews going further.

Comment: I though it would be completely impossible to delete answers by John Skeet. Shouldn't that just crash SO?

Comment: @BDL: wait 24 hours and they will automatically reanimate. Only special silver delete votes will kill them off completely.

Comment: @BDL it did - user profiles didn't work for awhile yesterday :)

Comment: @RBT I have had comments on answers of mine that were posted just 4 years ago, and I found them disorienting, as if I should reply immediately. Not that the comment(s) weren't valid or pertinent, but *sometimes* it's very difficult to remember why I wrote a line or chose specific word. I can only imagine what it must be like for someone who has answered 35 thousand questions in 12 years. And only now, I see this post is three years old. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a post gets deleted, either by the OP, reviewers or users with delete privileges, your comment history and any notifications you got are purged as well.

As all this is caching/controlled by jobs that run frequently you might find such comments and/or notifications in your profile or inbox if you pay close attention and are quick enough to check them out. After that they are gone and you'll only be able to find then back if you keep an url to the post and reach 10K so you can see deleted posts. And that still assumes the comments were worth keeping and haven't been removed by a moderator. To  see your deleted comments (and that of everyone else) you have to become a moderator ...