# When a question is deleted, only partial comment is in my inbox

Tags: bug, deleted-comments, global-inbox

Several times this past month I have had partial comments in my inbox, and when I click on them I get the "Page deleted by author" message.  All I have in my inbox is a partial message and no sender information.  Now there is no way to retrieve the entire comment or contact back the sender to ask for clarification!  Is it possible to put the entire comment and the sender in the Inbox instead of a useless "teaser" stub?  If I can't get the whole comment and sender any more, why not just delete the notification from my inbox?

Comment: If anything, the notification shouldn't be showing up at all. There's not much point in trying to respond to a comment on a deleted question.

Comment: Usually because [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - Not all comments require responses, or the comment may have been a valuable response TO me.  i.e.  `"Thanks for the help, I solved it by..."`  (in the Inbox)  and the remainder of the comment is in the `deleted comment bitbucket` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Comments on deleted posts *shouldn't* be showing up in your inbox at all, save for perhaps certain caching effects in edge cases.

See, for example:

- [Do deleted comments disappear from the targeted user's inbox?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378719/do-deleted-comments-disappear-from-the-targeted-users-inbox),
- [Deleted comments persist in the global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#65792), and
- [What happens to log history of comments done on a deleted post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348645/what-happens-to-log-history-of-comments-done-on-a-deleted-post/348647#348647)

Therefore, I think it's safe to say that the behavior you witnessed and describe here is a bug.

Comment: FWIW, I've had several of these deleted comments in the last week or so, (on Physics.SE, where I don't have enough rep to see deleted posts).

Comment: The bug persists in 2023